# Console Error: when using php script start & srcipt end

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have the following code which throws the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

I know its something simple, cant see it. Thank you in advance.

```
<?php $this->Html->scriptStart(array('block'=>'scriptBottom','inline' => false)); ?>
var phpRandom = "<?php echo json_encode($randomSponsor); ?>";
<?php $this->Html->scriptEnd();?>
```

Comment: `Unexpected identifier` is a javascript error. You need to "View Source" of your page, look at the generated javascript code. You'll find a syntax error.

Comment: you probably blew up JS by directly dumping text from PHP into a JS context. **NEVER** Do that. if you're building JS code using php, always use json_encode: `var foo = <?php echo json_encode($bar); ?>`. go look at the generated page ('view source'), and you'll probably find you built something like `var phpRandom  = "foo" bar";`, which is a flat-out syntax error.

Comment: Thanks guys! Got it.